# Оформление маркированного списка. Тупик

Tags: пунктуация

Рассудите хитрый маркированный список, который ввел в тупик нескольких человек.

Смотрим http://prntscr.com/8mxqa8

После подзаголовка "Диагностический комплекс при онкологических заболеваниях головного мозга" идет маркированный список. Вопрос, с какой буквы должен начинаться список: Заглавной или строчной?

Другой вариант. Меняем подзаголовок на "Какая диагностика проводится при онкологических заболевания головного мозга?" И тот же самый список. С какой буквы в этом случае должен начинаться список: Заглавной или строчной?

Comment: Подзаголовок с вопросительным зн***а***ком?

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае я бы добавила двоеточие и сделала бы пункты списка с маленькой буквы:

> Диагностический комплекс при онкологических заболеваниях головного мозга:
>   * консультация хирурга;
>   * ...
>   * ...
>   * л. пункция.

И я бы предложила сделать подзаголовок не таким выделяющимся, чтобы было больше похоже на единое предложение.

Во втором случае я предлагаю начинать *все* пункты списка с заглавной буквы и оформить их как отдельные предложения:

> Какая диагностика проводится при онкологических заболевания головного мозга?
>   * Консультация хирурга.
>   * ...
>   * ...
>   * Л. пункция.